# Maya: Import the same FBX file multiple times using Python

Tags: python, maya, autodesk, fbx

I've made a button in Maya that imports an .fbx file when pressed. When I press the button again to import the same .fbx it overwrites the one already in the scene, when the goal is to make a duplicate.

Example of what I'm trying to achieve: I press the button and it imports "sphere.fbx" into the scene as "sphere". I press the button again and it imports "sphere.fbx" into the scene as "sphere1".

This is all I'm using to import the .fbx:

```
cmds.file(shapePath + shapeList[value], i = True, mnc = True, ns = ":")
```

I've tried looking around for some solutions but I've had no luck.

Comment: Imports are best handled with namespaces, which is controlled by the `ns` argument in your `cmds.file` command. Try a few different strings there and I'm sure you'll see what I mean. It's not the exact solution you're looking for, but I daresay it's correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can't import the fbx file twice from what I can tell. What you can do as a workaround:

1. Attempt to import file
2. If it doesn't work, import the fbx file in as a reference
3. Make that reference part of the scene.

```
# Attempt to import fbx into the scene
# returnNewNodes(rnn) flag will tell us if it added anything
new_nodes = cmds.file(file_path, i=True, rnn=True)
print("Nodes added: {}".format(new_nodes))

# If nothing was added to the scene, import as reference
if not new_nodes:
    cmds.file(file_path, mnc=True, reference=True)
    # Make reference part of the scene
    cmds.file(file_path, importReference=True)
```